# How to align the popup ul relatively the parent li

Tags: html, css

There is a code with menu and pop-up windows.How to make the pop-up `ul`  in the middle of the parent `li`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#track-nav {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#track-nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.track-nav-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

#track-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s linear opacity;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#track-nav ul li {
  float: none;
}

#track-nav ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul li {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 35px;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 13px;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
}

#track-nav li:hover a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.clearfix_track:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.075s linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="track" class="container">
    <nav class="nav-menu">
      <ul id="track-nav" class="clearfix_track">
        <li>
          <a href="/">Main</a>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="consum" href="/product/catalog">Matherials</a><span>&gt;&gt;</span>
          <ul>
            <li>First gdgsfgs dfghdsfh</li>
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>Third</li>
            <li>Fouth</li>
            <li>Fifth</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/zhestkie-listovye-materialy">Color pencils</a><span>&gt;&gt;</span>
          <ul>
            <li>White pencil</li>
            <li>Red pencil</li>
            <li>Green pencil</li>
            <li>Blue pencil</li>
          </ul>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/listovoi-pvh">Color paper</a>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
          <ul>
            <li>fdfd</li>
            <li>dfdf</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "in the middle of the parent". Do you want the pop up centered relative to the parent instead of left justified?

Comment: Yes. So that, the pop up will be in the middle.

Comment: That is no more clear than before. Can you try using words other than "in the middle" to explain your goal?

Comment: Ok, I have parent li with dropdawn elements(in my case ul and children's li), this parent li has some length,and i want, that li will centered dropdawn ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use some `translateX` and `left` for the dropdown `ul` and also set `position:relative` to the parent `li`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#track-nav {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#track-nav li {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.track-nav-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

#track-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s linear opacity;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  min-width: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 100%;
}

#track-nav ul li {
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#track-nav ul a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul li {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#track-nav li:hover ul:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#track-nav li:hover a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.clearfix_track:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

#track-nav li:hover ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.075s linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="track" class="container">
    <nav class="nav-menu">
      <ul id="track-nav" class="clearfix_track">
        <li>
          <a href="/">Main</a>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="consum" href="/product/catalog">Matherials</a><span>&gt;&gt;</span>
          <ul>
            <li>First gdgsfgs dfghdsfh</li>
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>Third</li>
            <li>Fouth</li>
            <li>Fifth</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/zhestkie-listovye-materialy">Color pencils</a><span>&gt;&gt;</span>
          <ul>
            <li>White pencil</li>
            <li>Red pencil</li>
            <li>Green pencil</li>
            <li>Blue pencil</li>
          </ul>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/cat/listovoi-pvh">Color paper</a>
          <span>&gt;&gt;</span>
          <ul>
            <li>fdfd</li>
            <li>dfdf</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```